# Android Linear Layout not filling Scrollview

Tags: android, layout

I don't understand why I'm unable to get the linear layout (blue outline) to extend to the full size of the scrollview (the red, green and black areas) in the pic below.  I've tried different combinations of gravity and fill but no luck. What am I missing?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#111111"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="60dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:background="#999999"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagebar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:minHeight="70dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/b_p1"
                    android:layout_width="58dip"
                    android:layout_height="58dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_p1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="page1"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </FrameLayout>




            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/b_p2"
                    android:layout_width="58dip"
                    android:layout_height="58dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_p2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="page2"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </FrameLayout>




            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/b_p3"
                    android:layout_width="58dip"
                    android:layout_height="58dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_p3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="page3"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </FrameLayout>





            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/b_p4"
                    android:layout_width="58dip"
                    android:layout_height="58dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_p4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="page4"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:measureAllChildren="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#770000"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/searchbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="60dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/query"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:lines="1" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="60"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:maxHeight="48dip"
                    android:minHeight="48dip"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttons"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="60dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="60"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:maxHeight="48dip"
                    android:minHeight="48dip"
                    android:text="b1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="60"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:maxHeight="48dip"
                    android:minHeight="48dip"
                    android:text="b2"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="60"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:maxHeight="48dip"
                    android:minHeight="48dip"
                    android:text="b3"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="60"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:maxHeight="48dip"
                    android:minHeight="48dip"
                    android:text="b4"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/picbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/toast_frame" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/actionbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:background="#007700"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_warp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:text="warp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want like this

[image]

here is the corrected code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#999999"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pagebar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:minHeight="70dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/b_p1"
                android:layout_width="58dip"
                android:layout_height="58dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_p1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="page1"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/b_p2"
                android:layout_width="58dip"
                android:layout_height="58dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_p2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="page2"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/b_p3"
                android:layout_width="58dip"
                android:layout_height="58dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_p3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="page3"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/b_p4"
                android:layout_width="58dip"
                android:layout_height="58dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_p4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="page4"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#770000"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/query"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:lines="1" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:maxHeight="48dip"
                android:minHeight="48dip"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:maxHeight="48dip"
                android:minHeight="48dip"
                android:text="b1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:maxHeight="48dip"
                android:minHeight="48dip"
                android:text="b2"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:maxHeight="48dip"
                android:minHeight="48dip"
                android:text="b3"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:maxHeight="48dip"
                android:minHeight="48dip"
                android:text="b4"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/picbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@android:drawable/toast_frame" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#007700"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_warp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="warp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```